# Simulate shake gestures for a real device programmatically

Tags: android, robotium, acceptance-testing

I'm developing tests for an android app.

I can simulate the shake gesture on emulators by setting sensor values using android console.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
sensor status
acceleration: enabled.
magnetic-field: enabled.
orientation: enabled.
temperature: enabled.
proximity: enabled.
OK
sensor get acceleration
acceleration = 0:9.77622:0.813417
OK
sensor set acceleration 0:0:1
OK
```

This can be done programmatically by sending remote commands using a telnet library.

Now I want to run the same test against a real device. But I don't know the telnet port of it.

I wonder is this solution feasible on real devices?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Sensor Simulator. I just read this not implemented this. Link is

http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Comment: Yes, but I don't find a way to use it programmatically. Did I miss something?